# Insert data into Always Encrypted column using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, encryption, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, always-encrypted

I am facing an issue while trying to insert data into a SQL Server table with encrypted columns.

This is my approach.

I have created a table with three columns: [ID], [Name], [Password].
[Name] and [Password] columns are encrypted. `with COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [Test_CEK], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256')`

I have set "Column Encryption Setting = Enabled"
I have set "Parameterization for Always Encrypted"
And I have created a procedure to insert records into Test table as follows:

```sql
USE [TestDB] GO

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTest
    @name varchar(50),
    @pwd varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Name], [Password])  
    VALUES (@name, @pwd)
END
```

When I try to insert a new row using this procedure:

```
[ EXEC InsertTest 'Test','Test' ]
```

I get this error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure InsertTest, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(1) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'Test_CEK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'TestDB') collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

I want to insert data into SQL table through stored procedure. I do not want to use ADO.NET for SQL connection.

I want to implement the same functionality using Entity Framework.

This is how I am trying to call the procedure from c# but no luck.

[image]

Comment: `EXEC InsertTest 'Test','Test'` is the problem, you cannot pass literal strings because they will not be AE-nimized (a term i just made up). It probably works if you assign them to variables somewhere before the EXEC (if you use ssms) or use parameters to properly parametrize the AE call. It's all in the AE tutorials

Comment: I understand that we are not supposed to pass literals as direct parameters mentioned above, I have been trying to know a way to pass the parameters to the above procedures. Can you please describe how to pass the parameter in your way. 
Thanks for the reply

Comment: Just follow some tutorial: https://khaledelsheikh.medium.com/configuring-always-encrypted-on-azure-sql-by-using-azure-key-vault-and-entity-framework-core-aae687ff2c63 or even microsofts

Comment: @siggemannen, in the mentioned link we can find that the records are being added to Table using entity type object, but I want to add the same object using stored procedure.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the data types of the stored procedure match the data types of the table columns. Did you create the stored procedure before applying encryption to the column? Have you read the [`sp_refresh_parameter_encryption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refresh-parameter-encryption-transact-sql) documentation yet?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning , Thanks for the reply. 
I followed each and every step that is mentioned in the document you have mentioned and finally end-up with the following error message.
**'USE [TestDB]
GO
DECLARE at_return_value int
EXEC at_return_value = [dbo].[find_patient]
  at_SSN = N'99988877766'
SELECT 'Return Value' = at_return_value
GO'**

Error Message:
**Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables . The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'PLAINTEXT') and the expression near line '3' expects it to be DETERMINISTIC, or PLAINTEXT.**

Comment: @Prathapr putting code in the comments like that is rarely helpful; please use the [edit] feature to add such clarifications.

Comment: OK lets's start at teh beginning: which language are you using? C#, Python, PHP, something else? If you are doing it directly in SSMS there is a specific way you have to write the parameters in order for them to be encrypted on the client-side (you cannot pass them as plain-text), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-query-columns-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16#how-parameterization-for-always-encrypted-works

Comment: So the above example should have been `DECLARE @SSN nvarchar(20) = N'99988877766';` `DECLARE @at_return_value int; EXEC @return_value = dbo.find_patient at_SSN = @SSN; SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value;` with that first `DECLARE` on a separate line

Comment: @Charlieface, if i want to call the same procedure in c# code, using entity framework , how can i do that? Can you please describe.

Comment: Just follow the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/sqlclient-support-always-encrypted?view=sql-server-ver16#enabling-always-encrypted-for-application-queries and make sure all column data is parameterized (no literals).